# MySQL: How to find the latest data inserted by a User based on autoincremented ID

Tags: mysql

I have a DB table in which there are three fields:

```
ID--primary key/autoincremental
userID - user ID
data - any data
```

How can I found the latest/last data inserted by any particular user?

Comment: Can you think of how you might start to do that? Say, by filtering on something and sorting on another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get by `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
table
WHERE userID ='1'
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1 /* upto you*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use an`WHERE` condtion to specify your desired userID and `ORDER BY` your auto increment column `ID`

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE userID = ?
ORDER BY ID DESC
```